# Julia dataframes with specific column types

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to make a DataFrame of say size `N*K`, and I want some columns to be `Float64`, and other columns to be `Int64`. Is there a specific way of defining the DataFrame that allows me to do that?

This is my current approach:

```
df = convert(DataFrame, zeros(Float64, (N, K)))
df[:,K-2] = convert(Array{Int64,1}, df[:,K-2])
df[:,K-1] = convert(Array{Int64,1}, df[:,K-1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concatenate two DataFrames:

```
julia> hcat(DataFrame(Float64, 3, 5), DataFrame(Int64, 3, 3))
3×8 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1 │ x2 │ x3 │ x4 │ x5 │ x1_1 │ x2_1 │ x3_1 │
├─────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │
│ 2   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │
│ 3   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA   │ NA   │ NA   │
```

The `DataFrame` constructor also takes a vector of types as an argument:

```
julia> DataFrame([Float64, Float64, Int64, Int64], [Symbol("x$i") for i in 1:4], 3)
3×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1 │ x2 │ x3 │ x4 │
├─────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│ 1   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │
│ 2   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │
│ 3   │ NA │ NA │ NA │ NA │
```

You can construct the appropriate vector of types using concatenation:

```
julia> [repeat([Float64]; outer=4); repeat([Int64]; outer=2)]
6-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Float64
 Float64
 Float64
 Float64
 Int64  
 Int64
```